# Tensorflow Python Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, server

in vps with windows server 2012 R2

i install python 3.6.8 and tensorflow . keras

C++ 2015 , 2019 and windows server desktop extension is installed

but i have this error log

[Tensorflow python on windows server 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPnJ2.png)

I have no problem with my home system

It runs easily on my home system